# springxd JMS sink acknowledge propery

Tags: jms, spring-xd

I am unable to find any documentation on how I can use/customize the springxd JMS source acknowledge property.

Documentation only says - 
***JMS with Options
The jms source has the following options:
acknowledge
the session acknowledge mode (String, default: auto)***

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the spring framework documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html).

> acknowledge
>
> The native JMS acknowledge mode: auto, client, dups-ok or transacted. A value of transacted activates a locally transacted Session. As an alternative, specify the transaction-manager attribute described below.